# generic forumula to calculate based on row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For some reason I am calculating result of (A1/B1)*60....(A./B.)*60....up to (An/Bn)*60
This calculation starts for A1 B1 postion to An Bn and result I want to store in C1 to Cn.

Currently I am adding my formula in coloum C. As the number n is big I want to reduce my effort by doing some quick hack.

Any advice.

Comment: Really belongs on superusers group

Comment: You can double click on the little black square at the bottom-right corner of the cell C1 to fill in the whole column up to row *n*.

Answer (score 2):

1) add formula to C1

2) Select C1 with the mouse and copy it

3) without clicking on the spreadsheet cells, scroll down the sheet until you get to the last row you want the formula in.

4) hold down shift and click Cn cell

5) paste

Comment: For Keyboard Users From Step 2 above, press `CTRL + C `on C1, press `CTRL + left arrow`, press `CTRL + down arrow`, press `right arrow`, press `CTRL + SHIFT + up arrow`, press `CTRL + V`. Seems like a lot, but very quick use of keyboard!